# Carousel not working in ractive template

Tags: jquery, ractivejs

home/index.ract

```
<div class="row owl-carousel owl-theme row">
    {{#featured}}
    <div class="column small-12 medium-6 large-3 pan item">
    <a href="{{ link }}">
      <div class="griditem boxshadow">
          <div class="item-content">
            <h1 class="title">{{ title }}</h1>
            <p class="byline">By {{ subtitle }}</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    </div>
    {{/featured}}
    </div>
```

layout/index.ract

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/owl.carousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <cromly:content />
      /***ractive component**/
    </main>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/owl.carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var owl = $('#handpicks');
        owl.owlCarousel({
          itemsCustom : [
               [450, 1],
               [600, 2],
               [1024, 3],
               [1200, 4]
             ],
             navigation : true
        });

      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

All ractive templates are on NodeJs. Somehow owl carousel or [slickjs](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) is not working as it should. It doesn't show 4 items per slide. Instead, it showed the full number of items in a list (non-working carousel) or items disappeared - showed blank. Is it not possible to use jquery plugin in ractive template at all?

**Updated**

According to @martypdx

I tried:

```
 var main = Ractive.extend({
  el: 'main'
})
app = new main()

app.on({
    'onrender': function(){
        var owl = $('#handpicks');
        owl.owlCarousel({
              itemsCustom : [
                   [450, 1],
                   [600, 2],
                   [1024, 3],
                   [1200, 4]
                 ],
                 navigation : true
        });

    }
})
```

It is still not showing the carousel slide - in other word, it is blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your jquery code into the ractive onrender:

EDIT: put as ractive function

```
var main = Ractive.extend({
  el: 'main',
  onrender: function(){
    var owl = $('#handpicks');
    owl.owlCarousel({
       itemsCustom : [
               [450, 1],
               [600, 2],
               [1024, 3],
               [1200, 4]
       ],
       navigation : true
    });
  }
};
```

Or use the name if you want to use `on` method:

```
app.on( 'render', function(){
    var owl = //etc...
});
```

Comment: thanks. I looked into server.js and i saw "app.on" and I m not sure where to place it. hmm.

Comment: I have attempted as above and it is not showing carousel

Comment: seems like jquery is not going through. Do I need to have jquery as a require?

Comment: it's not clear from your code example where the ractive instance is being created. But jquery would need to be loaded __before__ you call `new Ractive()` or whatever component you're using